# Navigation Elements not lining up

Tags: html, css, sass, bulma

I am using bulma for a css framework and i ran into an interesting learning experience. I am trying to align the nav buttons to the bottom of the red field. However, as you can see they have shifted out of alignment. I have tried to apply an inline css style to them, however that does not correct the issue.

Can anyone point me in the right directory, it would be greatly appreciated.

https://codepen.io/robot43298/pen/WNGENNL

```
.navbar-end {
.button{
color: white;
font-size: 18px;
border: 2px dashed white;
background-color: red;
}
.dropdown-trigger{
margin-top: 15%;
display: inline;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
& li{
font-size: 16px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Remove this margin

```
.navbar-end .dropdown-trigger {
       margin-top: 15%; /* Remove this margin */
       display: inline;
       vertical-align: bottom;
  }
```

and add some padding here as per your need

```
.dropdown{
     padding-top: 20px;
   }
```

This should do the trick;

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and it made the navbar itself shift much further down than I would have liked.

Comment: Did you remove the margin-top first before adding the padding ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried looking your code in console, I added one line and removed one.
and it seems to work as per you expectation.
Do let me know if this what you wanted.

[image: Changes]

[image: Results]

Comment: Thank you for the help. Just out of curiosity, why the "!important". I have seen that at times but never really understood it.

Comment: margin-top was already provided by bluma, in order to override that rule I have used !important.

Based on CSS specificity rule, !important flag gets higher priority over other css property declaration for same element.